# UITableView detailTextLabel - iphone development

Tags: iphone, uitableview

why is "detailTextLabel" not working anymore?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text=[listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"hi";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try to post more code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the style of the cell, use this code while initializing the cell

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

For more information about the cell styles look at the [apple's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

You've chosen a cell style `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` that does not support a `detailTextLabel`

Try using a different style.

**edit**

You choose a style in the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier;` method. Have a look at the [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs which describes the available cell styles.

Comment: how can i do that ?  programatically or from IB?