# Displaying detailTextLabel in non-custom prototype UITableViewCell whilst using Storyboard

Tags: ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I wish these were sufficient answers to my problem:

- [In UITableView, cell.detailTextLabel.text isn't working… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834199/in-uitableview-cell-detailtextlabel-text-isnt-working-why)
- [Why is detailTextLabel not visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190648/why-is-detailtextlabel-not-visible)
- [UITableView detailTextLabel - iphone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801911/uitableview-detailtextlabel-iphone-development)
- etc...

Unfortunately, either I am too thick-headed to see my solution in these comments, or they do not address my problem.

I am stubborn, in that I believe I should be able to display a detail text label without creating a custom UITableViewCell, all while creating my interface through the storyboard. The default storyboard prototype cell does not have an option for style.  As well, no where in my code am I actually allocating this cell other than here; thus, I assume that it is being originally allocated in the storyboard to a default style that does not use detail text labels.

When I use the following code to populate cells, my detailTextLabel does not appear:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"This is never called!");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0: // boring cell
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Default label"];
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            break;

        case 1: // loading cells based on contents of core data
            {           
            // get some data from previously retrieved core data objects
            NSManagedObject *rowObj = [myObjects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            NSDate *someDate = (NSDate*)[rowObj valueForKey:@"timeStarted"];
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
            [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate: someDate];

            // we have the fields ready; populate the cell
            NSLog(@"This prints a valid date:%@", stringFromDate);

            // this, also, displays just fine
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Default text"];

            // this does not appear
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;
    break;
        }           
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I apologize in advance if this has been addressed elsewhere and my search-fu is lacking, or if there is a discussion of UITableViewCells and storyboards related to detail text label cell styles, but I have not seen them in my searches.

Specifically, what do I need to change in my code to set the style to use a detail text label while still using non-custom prototype UITableViewCells and keeping my storyboard intact?

Lastly, and this may be completely unrelated (please ignore if it is), if I generate many rows such that I can scroll down my table, all my rows appear fine other than there are a few (depending on how fast I scroll) that appear differently than the rest (text alignment). That is to say, as I understand it, I am seeing new cells being allocated/initialized without the same default settings I've specified in the storyboard. Note, the initWithStyle code below is still never called. If I am understanding this correctly, something is going on behind the scenes creating new cells, and I would like to know where so I can set the style preference. But again, if this is a symptom to an unrelated problem, please ignore, and I can post another question if it persists.

Sorry for the wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the top problem; the last paragraph in my question is an unrelated issue, I believe.

When using a storyboard, do not set your identifier to be the same identifier you use in your code; you are not going to use the default cell type used in your storyboard.  By sharing the same label, the properties of the storyboard's identified cell take precedence, it looks like.